# Can't get attribute of element in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I try to get element like HTML:

Good luck. You should read more at homepage

And I write this code to waiting for element show.

```
while (browser.FindElementByXPath("//p[@id='happy-text']").GetAttribute("style").IndexOf("display: block;") == -1)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Can't get values at first while loop.

So, I tried with `browser.FindElementByXPath("//p[@id='happy-text']").GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: block;")` is false but when to debug in this rows, first while, it can get values.

But when loop again it throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

I know this null but have any method to check when the element is visible.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector/xpath/any("")));

I use this for element to be visible in JAVA

Comment: It would help in answering if you include what problem you are trying to solve here? Usually, null reference exception is the easiest exception to fix. It appears to me from your code you want to wait till the element is loaded/visible in the browser. I suggest looking for implict/explicit wait provided by Selenium.

Comment: Thanks @Kishan Patel and Han Prasad. I was using `Wait` of Selenium but it's not working.